# Importing from excel and making a column memo

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am importing data from excel that works fine.

The problem I need to resolve is that when it imports I need one column to be memo before the data goes in. At the moment not all data is importing because of the column not set to memo.

**My Code:**

```
    Dim oExcel As Object, oWb As Object
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWb = oExcel.workbooks.Open(FileName:=strFile, _
Password:=strPassword)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "_tmp_table", strFile, -1
oWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
oExcel.Quit
Set oExcel = Nothing

Dim strClsExl As String
     strClsExl = "TASKKILL /F /IM Excel.exe"
     Shell strClsExl, vbHide
```

Any help on how to do this is appreciated

Comment: Why are you opening Excel and then doing nothing in the file? `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` doesn't require the file to be open.

Comment: The file is has a password

Answer (score 0):

If you set the import temp_table up beforehand with the appropriate field type already set to Memo, it will behave as you want it to.

Comment: I did try that - The problem is the file it imports from has a random number in column A1 whilst the rest has no data in column A. So when it imports its automatically trying to change the first column header which wont work as the A1 number changes all the time.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting changing the field name. Are the field names important?
I was saying make the table first and define the data type as Memo.